# Write to Button.Tag as class and read from it

Tags: c#, wpf

I have problem with my code. I´m triing to insert class with variables to Button.Tag so I used

```
Button Btn = new Button();
```

and insert class reference by this:

```
Tlacitko.Tag = new Pozice(poradiradek, poradisloupec);
```

and I have class Pozice:

```
class Pozice
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public bool zivotnost = false;
    public Pozice(int getX, int getY)
    {
        x = getX;
        y = getY;
    }
}
```

Now I don´t know, how to write new value into `zivotnost` because I used constructor only to write value into `x` and `y`. Second problem is that I don´t know how to get these value out. So please help me.

Comment: Tlacitko.Tag = new Pozice(poradiradek, poradisloupec); Looks to me like thats where you create your object. And u should be able to access it from there aswell

Comment: Get it back by `var pozice = (Pozice)Tlacitko.Tag;`, then access it as usual. And consider using english identifier names. It makes your code more easily readably for others like us.

Answer (score 0):

Get it back by

```
var pozice = (Pozice)Tlacitko.Tag;
```

then access it as usual:

```
pozice.zivotnost = true;
```

Comment: I would also advise to use `var pozice = Tlacitko.Tag as Pozice;`

Comment: @vasily.sib I would not recommend that, because you would correctly get an InvalidCastException when there is not a Pozice object in the Tag property, which would be a programming error (when the property is not null). You often see people using `as` without even checking the result for null. In case you have an error (i.e. an object of a different type than expected), you get a NullReferenceException, which is totally confusing. So as a general advice, only use `as` when there may be objects of potentially different types in a variable or property.

Comment: My advice would be to null check. Even if you absolutely know for sure the tag will "always" have an object of a given type then I would still null check. Whatever you do, don't end up with code whose logic is driven by exception handling if you can possibly help it.

Comment: @Andy I totally disagree. You hopefully want to know when you made an error, and put something into Tag that is not of the expected type. Using as with null checking will make this go unnoticed.

Comment: @Clemens using exceptions for a flow control is a bad practice. In your way that would be correct to `if (Tlacitko.Tag is Pozice) pozice = (Pozice)Tlacitko.Tag; else { ..deal_with_it.. }`

Comment: @vasily.sib I'm not talking about control flow. What I mean is to get an exception to become aware of a programming error you made during development.

Comment: @Clemens if you are not talking about flow control, that means that you are not handling this exception, right? Just kill your app and that's it?

Comment: Exactly that. Then you know you have made a programming error. When you are done with developing your application, there will never be anything else than on object of the expected type in the variable or property in question. The application is just not supposed to do anything sensible when there is something else in the variable or property. [Fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).